# I am not able to create Group in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to create a Group in Google Cloud Platform but I do not find a way to do it from the Console. How can I create that? I have searched to find anything to identify an option to create a Group but I cannot find it. And I am the admin of the project.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, what worked for me was turning on "Groups for Business" under "Apps->G Suite" the GSuite Admin Console. Only then did I see the groups in the CGP console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a Google Group to Google Cloud IAM, but you cannot create one. A Google group is not a Google Cloud feature. Google Groups existed before Google Cloud.

Go to [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com) to create a group. Then add the group to IAM.

Comment: many thanks. Indeed that is what I have done too. But I do not see how I can add that to IAM. Can please tell me? This error is what I see from IAM manage group button: "admin.google.com is for G Suite accounts only. Regular Gmail accounts cannot be used to sign in to admin.google.com"

Comment: You cannot sign in with a Google Group. You can only assign roles to a group.

Comment: ohh I see! I can create role with group now. Last question: can I only add members to groups from the https://groups.google.com and NOT from GCP Console, right? thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your last question. You can add any email address that is a Google Account (Gmail, etc) to a Google Group. You cannot modify a Google Group membership in the Google Cloud console.

Comment: sorry if it was unclear. In GCP Console I do not see how to manage Groups. So my question is, can I add users to Groups from the GCP Console? Or I can do it from the Group web site only? I am asking because again, in the GCP Console I do not see any way to manage Groups.

Comment: To modify a Google Group, go to the Google Groups website. The Google Cloud console does not manage Google Groups (as in membership changes).